# Retrieving jar file from JVM?

Tags: java, jvm

I run my jar file but I have accidentally deleted it. I would like to know that can I retrieve back the jar from Java virtual machine?

Comment: You also lost the source of the jar file as well?

Comment: I don't have the source file. It is not written by me

Comment: No chance to get a jar from the JVM, because the JVM opens the jar and unpacks it in the memory. Why not getting it from your original source?

Comment: Ok. JVM will not give you back the jar. **If you are really desperate**, I would spend half an hour trying to restore the deleted file from OS. Most OS (Linux, Windows) does not actually delete your file even after it is gone from the "Recycle bin". There are easy-to-use tools for Windows and simple commands for Linux to restore files, but with NO guarantee of success at that point.

Comment: if run with rm -rf, can recover? haha.

Comment: @JimmyLee - not that way.  But it may still be possible to recover files that have been deleted; see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80270/unix-linux-undelete-recover-deleted-files.  However, your question is not about programming, and is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are linux, the JVM is still running and has still has the file open then you can enumerate the open file descriptors via `lsof` and copy the jar file from `/proc/<pid>/fd/<descriptor number>`

Comment: BTW file descriptor `0` is stdin and `1` is stdout and if these have been redirected to a file you can access those (even memory mapping them) + 1

Comment: @the8472 Is your way hundred percent can work?

Comment: You give a good direction and I follow and search some information related to your post. Eventually I am able to recover the deleted file.